# Need to get output as select statement, instead of using dbms_output

Tags: oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor, ref-cursor

i want to add a sys_refcursor as out parameter in this procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APIN
(
ADT APT.A_DATE%TYPE,
DID APT.D_ID%TYPE
)
```

/* i want to add a sys_refcursor as out parameter in this procedure */

```
AS
TYPE VRC IS RECORD
(
V_DT DATE,
V_ID NUMBER
);
```

/*declaring the type for ref cursor*/

```
TYPE V_RC IS REF CURSOR RETURN VRC;
```

/* how can i use this as out parameter along with the in parameters.*/

```
R V_RC;
RC SYS_REFCURSOR;
V_CNT NUMBER := 0;
V_STATUS VARCHAR2(30);
```

/* i want to add this variable as column name in the result set*/

```
V_ST_DT DATE; 
V_ED_DT DATE;
BEGIN
V_ST_DT := TRUNC(TO_DATE(ADT,'DD/MM/YY'),'MM'); 
/*getting first date of the month*/
V_ED_DT := LAST_DAY(V_ST_DT); 
/*getting last date of the month*/
LOOP
OPEN RC FOR 
/* selecting v_cnt value using ref cursor*/
SELECT MAX(RN) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY P_ID) RN FROM APT
WHERE D_ID = DID
AND A_DATE = V_ST_DT);
FETCH RC INTO V_CNT; 
  IF V_CNT >= 10 THEN
    V_STATUS := ' NOT AVAILABLE ON ';
```

/* is there any way to add this vairable values into the column of the table apt?*/

```
 OPEN R FOR
    SELECT A_DATE, D_ID FROM APT
    WHERE D_ID = DID
    AND A_DATE = V_ST_DT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DID||V_STATUS||V_ST_DT);
```

/*instead of using dbms_output, i need to get output from select statement*/

```
  ELSE 
    V_STATUS := ' AVAILABLE ON ';
    OPEN R FOR
    SELECT A_DATE, D_ID FROM APT
    WHERE D_ID = DID
    AND A_DATE = V_ST_DT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DID||V_STATUS||V_ST_DT);
/*instead of using dbms_output, i need to get output from select statement*/
  END IF;
  V_ST_DT := V_ST_DT + 1; 
/*incrementing date variable to check next date*/
  EXIT WHEN V_ST_DT > V_ED_DT;
END LOOP;
CLOSE RC; 
/*closing the ref cursor*/
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to heaven:

1. change procedure to function
2. create an oracle type and collection of its type
3. fill the object every time in function
4. set the function type `pipelined`

   ```
   create type my_output as object(mycol1 number,mycol2 varchar2(200));

   create type my_collection as table of my_output;

   create function apin(...) return my_collection pipelined;
   ```

You can select it later as

```
select * from table(cast(apin as <yourcollectionname>));
```

See here [pipeline functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm) to learn about pipelined functions